# How to select MIN and MAX in Sql Server within required range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select `aid` from a sql server table having `MIN` and `MAX` `p_year`within the range i.e. in between `1990` and `2014`.

I have tried this query but it gives error i.e.

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
SELECT aid
FROM   sub_aminer_paper
WHERE  Min (p_year) = (SELECT p_year
                       FROM   sub_aminer_paper
                       WHERE  p_year >= 1990)
       AND Max (p_year) = (SELECT p_year
                           FROM   sub_aminer_paper
                           WHERE  p_year <= 2014)
```

The required output should the `aid` of those authors whose minimum p_year >= 1990 and maximum p_year <= 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT aid
FROM sub_aminer_paper 
GROUP BY aid
HAVING MIN(p_year) >= 1990 AND MAX(p_year) <= 2014
```

Comment: can we use here `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. Thanks

Comment: @tinka you can't use WHERE clause after GROUP BY. If you intent to filter before grouping you can use WHERE before GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select aid from sub_aminer_paper 
   group by aid
   having min(p_year) >= 1990 and max(p_year) <= 2014
```